# Replace ? in a column to appropriate value in SAS sql query?

Tags: sas

I have a data that has column A with following data

```
Column A
--------
1
2
?
2
```

I used the query:

```
proc sql;
select 
if A= '?' then A=., count(*) as N_obs 
from freq_sex_Partner
group by Number_of_sexual_partners;
quit;
```

This is not working. Please suggest how can i replace the ? to any standard value?

Comment: [Look here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0a85s0ijz65irn1h3jtariooea5.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL it's a CASE statement, not IF/THEN.

```
proc sql;
select 
case when a='?' then . 
else a end as a, count(*) as N_obs 
from freq_sex_Partner
group by Number_of_sexual_partners;
quit;
```

Or you could use an IFC() function as well.

```
proc sql;
select 
ifc(a='?', ., a) as a, count(*) as N_obs 
from freq_sex_Partner
group by Number_of_sexual_partners;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Column A contains `"?"` so it is character valued.  The @reeza code should be `then ""` or `ifc(a='?',"", a)`.  Also, if you do not also select the grouping variable the context of the `N_obs` is lost.

Suggest

```
data have;
input a $ nsp ;
datalines;
1 2
2 3
? 7
2 7
run;

proc sql;
  select
    nsp
  , case when a='?' then '' else a end as a
  , count(*) as nsp_count
  from have
  group by nsp
  ;
quit;
```

The query will also log the message `NOTE: The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data.` as Proc SQL is performing an automatic remerge of group aggregates with individual rows within the group.

Comment: I rearranged the code to: proc sql;
  select
    Number_of_sexual_partners
  , case when Number_of_sexual_partners='?' then '.' else Number_of_sexual_partners end as Number_of_sexual_partners
  , count(*) as nsp_count
  from freq_sex_Partner
  group by Number_of_sexual_partners
  ;
quit;  The code gives following error : ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types.
 ERROR: Result of WHEN clause 2 is not the same data type as the preceding results. How can i resolved the issue?

Comment: To me, this would indicated nsp is numeric and might already have a custom format that causes missing numeric to be displayed as `?`, if so, you might not need to do anything else.  Can you show the output from `Proc CONTENTS data=freq_sex_partner` ?